# How to call tensorflow_model_server from Nodejs, with an image

Tags: python, node.js, tensorflow, tfx

This is the metadata of my serving model

```
"metadata": {"signature_def": {
 "signature_def": {
  "serving_default": {
   "inputs": {
    "vgg16_input": {
     "dtype": "DT_FLOAT",
     "tensor_shape": {
      "dim": [
       {
        "size": "-1",
        "name": ""
       },
       {
        "size": "224",
        "name": ""
       },
       {
        "size": "224",
        "name": ""
       },
       {
        "size": "3",
        "name": ""
       }
      ],
      "unknown_rank": false
     },
     "name": "serving_default_vgg16_input:0"
    }
   }...
```

Sadly I don't know how to talk to it from NodeJs. How to transorm a local image to a valid 224,224,3 DT_FLOAT Tensor ...

In python, i can do it with this code, but I would like the nodejs version

```
import numpy as np
import requests
from keras.preprocessing import image

image_path = './data/black/fhb2l97vdi8qc0rt5ow3.jpg'
img = image.img_to_array(image.load_img(image_path, target_size=(224, 224))) / 255.
img = img.astype('float16')

payload = {
    "instances": [{'vgg16_input': img.tolist()}]
}

r = requests.post('http://ip:port/v1/models/color:predict', json=payload)
print(r.content)
```

So far my code

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var myImg = __dirname + '/../tensorflow2/data/black/0a13y2gtunswi8ox4bjf.jpg';



var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: `http://ip:port/v1/models/color:predict`,
    json:{ 
          instances: [{'vgg16_input': ??????}]
        }

};

request(options, function (err, resp, body) {
    if (err)
      cb(err);

      console.log(body);
  });
```

Maybe i could use some function from tensorflowjs ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image must be passed in JSON as list of lists of floats (*pixel* is list of 3 RGB *values*, *row* is list of *pixels* and *image* is list of *rows*).

We need to decode and resize the JPEG image. Install [sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) package with `npm install sharp`.

Image preparation is as follows:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const sharp = require('sharp');

function imgToJson(buffer) {
  var decoded = [];

  var h;
  var w;
  var line;
  var pixel;

  var b = 0;
  for (h = 0; h < 224; h++) {
      var line = [];
      for (w = 0; w < 224; w++) {
          var pixel = [];

          pixel.push(buffer[b++] / 255.0); /* r */
          pixel.push(buffer[b++] / 255.0); /* g */
          pixel.push(buffer[b++] / 255.0); /* b */

          line.push(pixel);
      }
      decoded.push(line);
  }

  return decoded;
}

async function prepare_image(imagePath) {
  var jpegData = fs.readFileSync(imagePath); /* for example sake synchronous */
  const buffer = await sharp(jpegData).resize(224, 224).raw().toBuffer();
  return imgToJson(buffer);
}
```

The result of `prepare_image` is future returning the list of lists of floats representing image. The last step is to perform request:

```js
var request = require('request');

async function perform_request(imagePath) {
  var decoded = await prepare_image(imagePath);
  var options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://ip:port/v1/models/color:predict',
      json: { 
            instances: [{'vgg16_input': decoded}]
      }
  };

  request(options, function (err, resp, body) {
      if (err)
        cb(err);

        console.log(body);
    });
}

perform_request("image.jpeg");
```

Comment: Thank you. js answer : 
{ predictions:
   [ [ 0.869870663,
       0.109581947,
       1.78813934e-7,
       0.00818741322,
       4.76837158e-7,
       0.00215744972,
       3.57627869e-7,
       0.00000619888306,
       8.14288654e-8,
       0.00000102930289 ] ] }


python answer  "predictions": [[0.979003787, 2.9951334e-05, 8.94069672e-08, 0.000181376934, 7.18832e-05, 0.00502485037, 6.68466091e-05, 0.00051087141, 3.17406625e-06, 4.25011876e-07]

weird that it's not the same prediction ...

Comment: Second alternative : 
{ error:
   'Input to reshape is a tensor with 153600 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 25088\n\t [[{{node sequential/flatten/Reshape}}]]' }

Comment: As mentioned in answer, the second alternative does *not* perform resize - therefore it assumes, that the image is *already* `(224, 224)`.

Comment: For clarity I've decided to remove the alternative solution (which does not support resizing, using jpeg-js). It is available in answer edit history.

Comment: I've fixed path passing (remove unused variable `myImg`). Please, retry this answer. Did you used output from `import request ...` Python script or directly from TensorFlow?

Comment: output from import request

Comment: Ok i used a 224x224 image made from Gimp and compare python and js version, and it's the same, great !